# How to speed up nested loops in python with concurrency?

Tags: python, concurrency

i have the following code:

```
def multiple_invoice_matches(payment_regex, invoice_regex):
    multiple_invoice_payment_matches=[]
    for p in payment_regex:
        if p["match_count"]>1:
            for k in p["matches"]:
                for i in invoice_regex:
                    if i["rechnung_nr"] ==k:
                        multiple_invoice_payment_matches.append({"fuzzy_ratio":100, "type":2,  "m_match":0, "invoice":i, "payment":p})

    return multiple_invoice_payment_matches
```

The sizes of `payment_regex` and `invoice_regex` are really huge. Therefore, the code snippet give above takes too much time to return the result. How can I speed up running time of this code?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the `numba` library, if your data has the possibility of parallelization, rewrite your function using the numba library would definitely speed up your code.

Without the dimensions of size and how your data is structured it's kind of hard to give a general approach to optimize your function.

Answer (score 0):

I could say partition your data into multiple ranges (either by `payment_regex`, or by `invoice_regex`, or both) and then add those partitions to a work queue that is processed by multiple threads. Wait for those threads to finish (i.e.: join them), and then construct your final list based on the partial results you got for each partition.

This will work well in other programming languages, but unfortunately, not in **Python**, because of **GIL** - the **Python**'s **Global Interpreter Lock**.

If you don't know much about **GIL** [here](https://realpython.com/python-gil/)'s a decent article, saying:

```
The Python Global Interpreter Lock or GIL, in simple words, 
is a mutex (or a lock) that allows only one thread to hold 
the control of the Python interpreter. 
[...]
The impact of the GIL isn’t visible to developers who execute 
single-threaded programs, but it can be a performance bottleneck 
in CPU-bound and multi-threaded code.
```

To evade **GIL** you basically have two options:

- (1) spawn multiple **Python** processes and use shared memory for backing up your data => concurrency will now rely on the OS for switching between processes (e.g.: use `numpy` and shared memory, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html))
- (2) use a **Python** package that can manipulate your data and implements the multi-threading model in C, where **GIL** is not effective (e.g.: use `numba`)

You may ask yourself *then why Python supports multi-threading in the first place*?

Multi-threading in **Python** is mostly useful when the threads are blocked by IO operations (read/write of files, sockets, etc.) or by other system calls that put the thread in the sleep state. That's where **Python** releases the **GIL** lock and other threads can operate concurrently while some are at sleep.